# Facebook App/Page Tab with xmlHttpRequest doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: ajax, facebook, xmlhttprequest

I have e really big problem with firefox and facebook.
I mad an application on my webserver which uses xmlHttpRequest. I added this application to a facebook tab on a test facebook page. It works with IE, Chrome, Safari  but not with firefox.

The request just keeps loading until timeout.

The JS functions i'm using:

```
function createXmlHttpRequest() {
 try {
   if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined') {
     return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   } else if (window["XMLHttpRequest"]) {
     return new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
 return null;
};


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
 var status = -1;
 var request = createXmlHttpRequest();
 if (!request) {
   return false;
 }

 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4) {
     try {
       status = request.status;
     } catch (e) {

     }
     if (status == 200) {
       callback(request.responseXML, request.status);
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
     }
   }
 }
 request.open('GET', url, f);
 try {
   request.send(null);
 } catch (e) {
   changeStatus(e);
 }
};

function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}

function downloadScript(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

i call it through downloadUrl()

The Headers from the requested files:

```
header('Access-Control: allow <*>');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER');
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

i really tried everything, but it won't work in firefox...

what i've noticed: by observing firebug while loading this app in the facebook tab i could see that facebook is not requesting the adress given in the source, but other ones like: https://0-317.channel.facebook.com/pull?channel=p_1495135952&seq=389&partition=7&clientid=420773d2&cb=682&idle=0&state=active

i think it's surely firefox cross domain policy... but how can i solve this problem?

Anyone had the same problems ?

I thank you in advance.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the problem. 
Facebook is using UTF-8, but my page wasn't. So the stopped at the umlauts.
So it wasn't the Request at all.